# Using arrays in VBA to apply a key to recode item responses

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a data set with item responses to multiple tests. I want to recode the responses based on the correct response, which can be read from file. The tests are of different lengths and the number of records can vary depending on the test and the data set it is applied to. An example, data set may have 400 records with responses to 50 reading items, 40 maths items 30 spelling items and the like. 
Presently I am recoding each item response as shown in code below. I want to read in my 50 correct answers and apply it to responses in the corresponding 50 columns (CV:ES) and then use the same/similar code structure to apply to other test responses in other columns.

```
Sub readscore27()
Dim readkey(1) As String
readkey(1) = "A"

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyCell As Range
Sheets("output2").Select
'Step 2:  Define the target Range.
Set MyRange = Range("dv2", Range("dv" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
'Step 3:  Start looping through the range.
For Each MyCell In MyRange
'Step 4:  Do something with each cell.
  If MyCell.Value = "^" Then
  MyCell.Value =readkey(1)
 ElseIf MyCell.Value = "--" Then
  MyCell.Value = "-"
 ElseIf IsEmpty(MyCell) Then
  MyCell.Value = ""
 End If
'Step 5: Get the next cell in the range
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear at all how your current code relates to the description of what you want to do.  Your question would be easier to answer if you include example data for each part of your process.

Comment: Thanks Tim,Current code is

Comment: Thanks Tim, Current code is what I am doing 50 times over. The code example is for my 27th variable. The correct response has been assigned to 'readkey' and the responses to recode are in column 'dv' of sheets 'output2'

Comment: So the only possible responses are ^, --, or nothing ?

Comment: No, anything else gets left unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more generic by adding some parameters to `readscore`.

Example below.

```
Sub Tester()

    readscore "DV", "A"
    readscore "DW", "B"
    readscore "DX", "C"

End Sub



Sub readscore(colLetter, readkey)
    Dim c As Range, myRange As Range, v

    With Sheets("output2")
        Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(2, colLetter), _
                      .Cells(.Rows.Count, colLetter).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each c In myRange
        v = c.Value
        If v = "^" Then
            c.Value = readkey
        ElseIf v = "--" Then
            c.Value = "-"
        ElseIf Len(v) = 0 Then
            c.Value = ""
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```